# New traceparent id created in spring kafka in batch mode for distributed services - Disjoint traces

Tags: java, spring-kafka, distributed-system, open-telemetry, jaeger

I am using spring kafka in a distributed microservice and opentelemetry java agent to generate traces. The consumer is receiving the traceparent ID in header, however, the opentelemetry agent is not able to create a new span under the existing trace ID. Rather it is creating a new trace ID for each services, due to which the traces for microservices are not getting stiched.

Is there a way I can fix this using manual instrumentation?

Comment: Without knowning more details it's hard to say. Can you provide the versions of the agent, and any relevant components.If you can also provide minimal example of the relevant code, that is also helpful.